# Unable to access Milvus application

Tags: macos, milvus, vector-database

I installed Milvus on my mac using the documentation https://milvus.io/docs/install_standalone-docker.md

After following all the steps I am able to see in my docker desktop under milvus name 3
images are running and the standalone is running on 19530 and 9091.

However when I open localhost:19530 nothing shows up and in case of localhost:9091 it shows 404 page not found.

I also see fail connecting to server when I tried using a python script.

What could be the issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

19530 is the grpc port, and 9091 is for web service(API). So you could not use a browser to visit via those ports.
If you want to use UI tools to manage Milvus, you could try [Attu](https://github.com/zilliztech/attu/)